# Complex SQL I don't want to convert in a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I would like to have your assistance in order to know if it's possible to achieve the desired query without needing a stored procedure. I will try to explain myself as good as I can.

I have a similar structure to this:

```
PK / FK / DateTime / Value
1  / 68 / 10:30    / 60.5
2  / 68 / 09:30    / 10.5
3  / 61 / 05:30    / 01.0
4  / 58 / 04:30    / 22.2
5  / 58 / 01:00    / 15.0
```

These rows are defining some kind of event wich is described by the foreign key (FK). What I want to achieve is to get the two most recent rows for a set of events (FK).

Some kind of

```
SELECT TOP 2 * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE FK IN (68,58) 
ORDER BY DATETIME DESC
```

, but obtaining two rows of every FK in the IN clause.

In natural language, the desired operation is to iterate through FK in the IN clause and make a

```
SELECT TOP 2 * 
FROM TABLE 
ORDER BY DATETIME DESC.
```

I would like to know if it's possible to express that in one SQL.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option

```
SELECT
    B.*
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT FK FROM MyTable) A
    CROSS APPLY
    (
    SELECT TOP 2 * 
    FROM TABLE T
    WHERE T.FK = A.FK
    ORDER BY DATETIME DESC
    ) B
```

Or

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT *
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FK ORDER BY DATETIME DESC) AS RowNum
   FROM
      Table
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RowNum <= 2
```

Comment: I can see how your answer is *much* better than mine. Learning every day :-) +1

Comment: That's the spirit klausbyskov, awesome level shown here.

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 3):

```
    SELECT d.*
    FROM(
         SELECT DISTINCT FK FROM YourTable
         ) AS y
    OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 2 * 
      FROM YourTable AS y1
        WHERE y1.FK = y.FK
        ORDER BY DATETIME DESC
    ) AS d
```

Comment: Thanks AlexKuznetsov! Works also,

Comment: @Jacob84: this may work better with OUTER if you want FK from "y" and NULL from "d". My solution won't do that

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a union:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM TABLE WHERE FK = 68 ORDER BY DATETIME DESC
UNION
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM TABLE WHERE FK = 58 ORDER BY DATETIME DESC
```

Comment: Sorry, but who voted this up? -1 Not really a general solution, is it because question says "but obtaining two rows of every FK in the IN clause." And why not UNION ALL anyway?

Comment: As Gbn says, sorry klausbyskov, I've made a mistake explaining the problem, the FK IDs are variable, so I don't know how many UNIONS I have to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT D.*
FROM ( 
   SELECT t.*
      ,  ROW_NUMBER = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
              PARTITION BY FK 
              ORDER BY DateTime DESC
         ) 
   FROM Table AS t
) AS D
WHERE D.ROW_NUMBER <= 2
```

Or user RowNumber